# Can we upgrade targetframework versions as netstandard and netcoreapp to a .net framework version?

Tags: .net, .net-standard, target-framework, netcoreapp3.1

I have projects in a repository with trarget framewrk version as lower .net framework versions(2.0,3.0,3.5..etc). I need to upgrade them to higher framework version(v4.8) due to some security vulnerabilities.

[image]

But I found that few project's .csproj file has targetframework as netstandard2.0 and netcoreapp2.0. E.g.,
[image]

[image]

Below are my questions,

1. What is the the difference between .net framework, netstandard and netcoreapp?
2. Do I need to upgrade projects with targetframework as netstandard and netcoreapp to .net framework version v4.8 in my case? Will there be any security vulnerabilities if I don't upgrade them?

Any help or direction on this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're better-off creating new empty `.csproj` project files using VS's New Project Wizard instead of trying to edit an existing [old-style project file](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/) - pretty much every MSBuild property defined in the old-style (pre-2016) project files is gone or replaced in the new style - especially with how NuGet packages work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [official documentation about NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) would be the best thing to read in this case.

Every NET standard version defines a subset of API that are included on a specific implementation of the runtime framework (e.g. .NET 4.8, netcoreapp3.1 or NET 7).

Also [this image](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/media/cross-platform-targeting/platforms-netstandard.png) could be helpful.

About your first question: netstandard2.0 is implemented both by NET4.8 and netcoreapp3.1, but not by the older versions of .NET framework (2.0, 3.0, 3.5...).
For example, on a project that targets NET4.8 framework you can reference a netstandard2.0 library, whereas this is not possible from a NET3.5 project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do the projects with targetframework version as .netcoreapp requires upgrading to v4.8 in my case?

Comment: Actually, this choice is based on your need: [Choose between .NET and .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server)

Comment: @Parashuram You should try to target atleast .NET Standard if you want your libraries to be consumable in future with .NET releases